# New object is being added every time I type a letter

Tags: reactjs

How can we prevent input onchange adding new object everytime we type a letter? I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. Thanks in advance y'all.

```
import { React, useState }  from 'react';
// Bootstrap Component
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';

const Profile = () => {
    const [newCourseObj, setNewCourseObj] = useState(
        [
            {
                course: "",
                level: ""
            }
        ]
    );

    return (
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
            setNewCourseObj( test => [
                ...test,
                {
                    course: e.target.value
                }
            ]);
        }}
        />
        <TextField
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => {
            setNewCourseObj( test => [
                ...test,
                {
                    level: e.target.value
                }
            ]);
        }}
        />
        <Button variant="light" type="submit" className="save"><span className="material-icons"> done </span></Button>
                                                    
        <div>{JSON.stringify(newCourseObj, null, 2)}</div>
                    
        </form>
    );
}
```

export default Profile;

[image]

Comment: You are adding the new object “onChange” which fires when the text input changes, aka you type something. Try using “onBlur” assuming you want the object to be added when the user finishes typing and clicks out of the input field.

Comment: How can we do that? Can you add your answer

Comment: Replace the “onChange” prop in your TextFields with “onBlur”. This should be rather self explanatory if you indeed wrote this code.

Comment: [ { "course": "", "level": "" }, { "course": "HTML" }, { "level": "55" } ]

they are being separated

Comment: Also your first TextField is expecting a “number” when it should look for “text” as you are asking for a course name which is a string. I would actually just have one input that asks for a “pattern” like “name number” and when the input blurs, you just execute a function that splits the name and number (parse the number accordingly to convert from string), create an object and push onto the state variable.

Comment: Exactly they are separated since you have 2 fields, each pushing on a blur. Try what I said with the one field.

Comment: I want to achieve sometime like this [ { "course": "HTML", "level": "55" } ]

Comment: course and level should be in one object not in separate

Comment: @lbragile Do you have any suggestion how we can achieve it? Please add your answer

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Or are you simply waiting for someone to solve your problem?

Comment: See my answer below, I've included a sandbox where you can check that it works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-fire-m1kod?file=/src/App.js

Please consider accepting and upvoting if my answer helps you.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { React, useState }  from 'react';
// Bootstrap Component
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';

const Profile = () => {
  const [newCourseObj, setNewCourseObj] = useState([]);

  const handleTextInput = (e) =>{
    // make sure input matches "word of at least length 1 + space + number of at least length 1"
    if(e.target.value.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)/)){
      let [course, level] = e.target.value.split(" ");
      setNewCourseObj([...newCourseObj, { course, level: parseInt(level, 10) }]);
    } else {
      alert("Bad input")
    }    
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => alert("submitting");
  
  return (
    <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField type="text" onBlur={handleTextInput} />
      <Button variant="light" type="submit" className="save"><span className="material-icons"> done </span></Button>                                             
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(newCourseObj, null, 2)}</pre>               
    </form>
   );
}

export default Profile;
```

### Sandbox Example

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-fire-m1kod?file=/src/App.js)

Notice how the `level` property of the pushed objects is a **number**, while the `course` is a **string**.

Also, the initial state should be an empty array or you will append to an existing object that has no information.